# Get and Set values of Contract remotely via Web3j returns 0 and null

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, web3j

I have my two Quorum nodes setup on two different machines A(X.X.X.1) and B(X.X.X.3) and I am trying to interact with the smart contract from a different machine C(X.X.X.4) via Web3j. Below is the smart contract and the code snippet for interacting with the same:

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract DASKDetails {

 struct ASKStructAdditionalDetails{
    //check string
    uint ASKId;
    uint transactionId;
    string transactionStatus;
  }


  ASKStructAdditionalDetails public aSKStructAdditionalDetails;


  function storeASKStructAdditionalDetails(uint ASKId ,uint transactionId ,string transactionStatus) public returns(uint result) {
    aSKStructAdditionalDetails.ASKId = ASKId;
    aSKStructAdditionalDetails.transactionId = transactionId;
    aSKStructAdditionalDetails.transactionStatus = transactionStatus;
    return 1;
  }

  function getASKDetails() public constant returns(uint ASKId ,uint transactionId ,string transactionStatus) {
        return (aSKStructAdditionalDetails.ASKId,
                aSKStructAdditionalDetails.transactionId,
                aSKStructAdditionalDetails.transactionStatus);
    }

 }
**********************************************
I deploy the contract from the CLI on machine A and get a contract address (CA). I use this contract address to load the contract and call the setEnqMetadataOnBlockchain() method to set the values onto blockchain. I get a transaction receipt (thereby confirming that the transaction was mined). Below is the code snippet for the same:


     private static ASKDetailsLatest2 loadContract() {
        Quorum quorumNode1 = Quorum.build(new HttpService("http://X.X.X.1:RPCPORT"));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         list.add("Public key of recipient node");
         ClientTransactionManager ctm = new ClientTransactionManager(quorumNode1,
                 "fromAddr", list);
         ASKDetailsLatest2 enqContract = null;

         try {
             enqContract = ASKDetailsLatest2
                     .load("ContractAddr", quorumNode1, ctm, Contract.GAS_PRICE, Contract.GAS_LIMIT);

         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return enqContract;

     }

     private static String setEnqMetadataOnBlockchain(ASKDetailsLatest2 enqDetCont) {

         try {


             System.out.println("Store function call");
             rec = enqDetCont.storeASKStructAdditionalDetails(new Uint256(BigInteger.valueOf(100)), 
                     new Uint256(BigInteger.valueOf(100)), new Utf8String("PENDING")).get(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
             System.out.println("Transaction hash is "+rec.getTransactionHash()+"  to Address is:"+rec.getContractAddress());


         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return ASKContractAddr;
     }

     private static void getEnqMetadataOnBlockchain(String ASKCA) {
         Quorum quorumNode4 = Quorum.build(new HttpService("X.X.X.3"));

         List<Type> inputParameters = new ArrayList<Type>();

         List<TypeReference<?>> outputParameters = new ArrayList<TypeReference<?>>();
         outputParameters.add(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {});
         outputParameters.add(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {});
         outputParameters.add(new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {});

         Function function = new Function("getASKDetails", inputParameters, outputParameters);

         String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
         System.out.println("ASKCa is :"+ASKCA);
         try {
             org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthCall response = quorumNode4
                     .ethCall(Transaction.createEthCallTransaction("fromAddr",
                             ASKCA, encodedFunction), DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
                     .sendAsync().get(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

             List<Type> someTypes = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(response.getValue(), function.getOutputParameters());

             System.out.println("4 : response is: " + someTypes.size());
             for (int i = 0; i < someTypes.size(); i++) {
                 System.out.println(someTypes.get(i).getValue());
             }

         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }

 }
```

However, when I try to get the value back and print it via Web3j, I am getting null, 0 values from uint and string respectively. Any idea what this could be due to?

PS: I can confirm that the values are being set and get successfully if I do the entire process on different machines (A,B) from backend (i.e Without using web3j).